# What is the fastest way to calculate how many rows in a matrix are all TRUE using R or RCpp?

Tags: r, performance, rcpp

#### Synopsis

I want to find the fastest way to calculate how many times a subset of
cols defined by `vec` from a matrix of logicals are *all* `TRUE`:

#### Minimal example:

```
mlgl <- structure(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), .Dim = c(15L, 5L
                    ), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("l1", "l2", "l3", "l4", "l5")))
mlgl
#>          l1    l2    l3    l4    l5
#>  [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#>  [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#>  [5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#>  [6,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#>  [7,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#>  [8,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#>  [9,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> [10,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [11,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#> [12,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [13,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [14,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [15,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

And a vector to subset by, defined by `vec`:

```
vec <- c("l1", "l3")
```

I want to know how many times all the variables in `vec` are `TRUE`. For
this vec the expected answer is `4` (rows 6, 11, 13 and 15). the fastest
way I can think of doing this is:

```
sum(rowSums(mlgl[,vec]) == length(vec))
#> [1] 4
```

compiler::cpmfun did not help with either of these:

```
microbenchmark(
  sum(apply(mlgl[, vec], 1, all)), 
  sum(rowSums(mlgl[,vec]) == length(vec)),
  unit = "eps"
  )
#> Unit: evaluations per second
#>                                      expr       min       lq     mean
#>           sum(apply(mlgl[, vec], 1, all))  4416.649 14013.85 13696.17
#>  sum(rowSums(mlgl[, vec]) == length(vec)) 27348.557 63477.96 67712.96
#>    median       uq      max neval cld
#>  14210.30 14397.81 14766.03   100  a 
#>  65017.46 75503.08 81175.42   100   b
```

I would love some alternative solutions or suggestions to do better than
this in R or with RCpp.

**Update:** added some solutions that help out as an answer... another order of magnitude would be nice though.

Comment: So I haven't used `unit="eps"` before, is higher better?

Comment: @RichardScriven more evaluations per second is "better" yes.  If (as I am in this case) you want to evaluate the call many times (on different inputs or subsets). Ideally, at the scale this example would be on the order of 1E6 eps.

Comment: Roger that.  Just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that we can improve speed here by using an integer vector to select the columns, instead of a character vector. With this method, there is no name matching or use of any attributes happening behind the scenes.  We'll give `fmatch()` and `match()` a try.

The following line marked `integer` just shows how quick using an integer vector alone can be.

```
library(fastmatch)
microbenchmark(
    fmatch  = sum(rowSums(mlgl[, fmatch(vec, colnames(mlgl))]) == length(vec)),
    match   = sum(rowSums(mlgl[, match(vec, colnames(mlgl))]) == length(vec)),
    integer = sum(rowSums(mlgl[, c(1L, 3L)]) == length(vec)),
    unit = "eps"
 )
# Unit: evaluations per second
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   fmatch 16146.74 49468.25 50143.24 50823.34 52064.45 54404.00   100
#    match 45108.03 58503.55 59741.99 59724.68 61135.91 64930.85   100
#  integer 41023.96 80411.72 81827.19 83004.78 85429.93 88944.23   100
```

Actually is seems we didn't need to load *fastmatch* after all, as `match()` did better.  Overall, using an integer vector instead of character name-matching definitely improves speed here.

I'm confident there will be a nice quick Rcpp answer posted shortly.

**Update:** Here's one more method using `which()` and `length()` that is also very good.

```
microbenchmark(
    which = length(which(rowSums(mlgl[, vec]) == length(vec))),
    unit = "eps"
)
# Unit: evaluations per second
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
#  which 26816.12 81502.91 81858.62 83156.76 84566.6 87850.3   100
```

Comment: thanks for the go! I've added my current solution as an answer for reference seems as the `.Internal(rowSums(...` is faster that what I can do with Rcpp.

Answer (score 3):

#### Update my current sol'n here:

```r
mlgl <- structure(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
                    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), .Dim = c(15L, 5L
                    ), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("l1", "l2", "l3", "l4", "l5")))
vec <- c("l1", "l3")
```

initial sol'n

```
initial <- function() {
  sum(rowSums(mlgl[,vec]) == length(vec))
}
```

`.Internal(...` sol'n (which is not really allowed)

```
current <- function() {
  sml <- mlgl[,vec]
  dims <- dim(sml)
  sum(.Internal(rowSums(sml, dims[1], dims[2], FALSE)) == dims[2])
}
```

Thus my attempt at a simple solution with c++:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('int cpp_sum_trues(LogicalMatrix x) {
  int nrow = x.nrow(), ncol = x.ncol();
  int out = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
      total += x(i, j);
    }
    if (total == ncol) {
      out += 1;
    }
  }
  return out;
}')
a_cpp_soln <- function() {
  sml <- mlgl[,vec]
  cpp_sum_trues(sml)
}
```

timings:

```
microbenchmark(initial(), current(), a_cpp_soln(), times = 1e3, unit = "eps")
#> Unit: evaluations per second
#>          expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max
#>     initial() 13468.01  69223.31  70388.61  71622.98  74239.05  81652.65
#>     current() 22163.12 161407.47 168268.59 169319.34 180619.56 211595.43
#>  a_cpp_soln() 28041.84 140007.02 151792.51 152288.15 167841.56 186950.83
#>  neval cld
#>   1000 a  
#>   1000   c
#>   1000  b
```

Comment: Note that calling `.Internal` directly is not allowed by CRAN, and the API to internal functions can change without warning.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich thanks i have updated to reflect this.